# How to format Google Chart's Formatted Values using Java/JSON

Tags: java, json, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Chart's formatted value, but my graph displays with the formatted string [image]

(I only want it to display San Diego, CA). I am adding this in a Java file, using a JSONArray to store all of the ArrayToTable data. I have tried storing the information as a string, which causes the picture's issue, as an array and list of objects (keys being v and f) and strings, and have tried spacing and quotations of all possible ways (I'm happy to provide code for any of these methods). I am passing it into google with

```
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
```

and have also tried

```
google.visualization.DataTable();
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'value');
    data.addRows(dataArray);
```

but still, no luck. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to play with ?

Comment: @WhiteHat It is a very long output, but one entry looks like this `["{v:'154000-0',f:'154000'}","income",5,0]` using the manual string input option

Comment: @coding_idiot I'm not sure that's possible. There's a primary java file formatting the info, and connecting to a database to pull data and format through variable references. Is there a specific bit of code I can upload/modify to work in a fiddle that would help?

Comment: there shouldn't be quotes outside of the brackets, _bad_ --> `["{v:'154000-0',f:'154000'}","income",5,0]` -- _good_ --> `[{v:'154000-0',f:'154000'},"income",5,0]`

Comment: @WhiteHat Yea I noticed that difference, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @WhiteHat I just turned it into a JSON Object and it fixed it!!! Thank you so much!! I've been on this bug for hours!